# How to handle android lifecycle in flutter android plugin package

Tags: android, flutter, android-lifecycle

I need to know the current state of the flutter app view in an android plugin package.

For now, I observe the state in the flutter view with https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/WidgetsBindingObserver-class.html and pass it then to my plugin.

As this seems sometimes not perfect (the first event is not passed on Android) I would like to get the state directly from the android plugin.

In the plugin I get the registrar and can its activity, but how do I observe the state of it?

Comment: Duplicate question also at: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56974192

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flutter doesn't provide hooks for these lifecycle events.

Android Jetpack (formerly Architecture Components) added a nice way to receive lifecycle events from an activity:

[Handling Lifecycles with Lifecycle-Aware Components](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle)

Downside: It only works when the activity is an `AppCompatActivity`. Flutter apps are usually based on a simple `Activity`, so you have to tell your users to use an `AppCompatActivity` instead.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the suggestion. So I have to stay with my approach or the AppCompatActivity.

Answer (score 3):

Kotlin version

Inside your plugin code:

```
class MyFlutterPlugin: FlutterPlugin, MethodCallHandler, ActivityAware {

/// onAttachedToEngine, onMethod call was hidden due to irrelevance in this example

    override fun onAttachedToActivity(binding: ActivityPluginBinding) {
        (binding.lifecycle as HiddenLifecycleReference)
                .lifecycle
                .addObserver(LifecycleEventObserver { source, event ->
                    Log.e("Activity state: ", event.toString())
                })

    }
}
```

Don't forget about unregister and re-attach the observer in

> onDetachedFromActivity

> onReattachedToActivityForConfigChanges

> onDetachedFromActivityForConfigChanges

methods

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, it gives you all the lifecycle events which the OP is asking for in [`AppLifecycleState`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/AppLifecycleState.html) like OnPause, OnResume etc. `ActivityAware` is more limited, it only tells you when the plugin is attached / unattached from the activity, or when the activity is destroyed for a config change

Answer (score 1):

Support for lifecycle callbacks in the android plugin is added. Please [refer](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/plugin-api-migration)

```
public class MyPlugin implements FlutterPlugin, ActivityAware {
  //...normal plugin behavior is hidden...

  @Override
  public void onAttachedToActivity(ActivityPluginBinding activityPluginBinding) {
    // TODO: your plugin is now attached to an Activity
  }

  @Override
  public void onDetachedFromActivityForConfigChanges() {
    // TODO: the Activity your plugin was attached to was
    // destroyed to change configuration.
    // This call will be followed by onReattachedToActivityForConfigChanges().
  }

  @Override
  public void onReattachedToActivityForConfigChanges(ActivityPluginBinding activityPluginBinding) {
    // TODO: your plugin is now attached to a new Activity
    // after a configuration change.
  }

  @Override
  public void onDetachedFromActivity() {
    // TODO: your plugin is no longer associated with an Activity.
    // Clean up references.
  }
}
```