# How to get Android Activity Lifecycle Events in Flutter Plugin?

Tags: android, android-activity, flutter, flutter-plugin

How can we get Android Activity Lifecycle Events in flutter plugin development? I don't want this in dart side, I want it in `Java/Kotlin` plugin side..

I tried this,

```
class MyPlugin() : MethodCallHandler, PreferenceManager.OnActivityDestroyListener, PreferenceManager.OnActivityStopListener {

    override fun onActivityDestroy() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Activity Destroyed")
    }

    override fun onActivityStop() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Activity Stopped")
    }

    override fun onMethodCall(call: MethodCall, result: Result) {

    }

}
```

But these are returning nothing.

Comment: Duplicate question also at: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53883813

Comment: This is not actually a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/50131598 (_Flutter App lifecycle (Android/iOS)_), though, and shouldn't have been closed as such. That question deals with app lifecycle (and in Dart), this question deals with plugin lifecycle (and on Android in Java/Kotlin).

Comment: @ArtoBendiken You are right, its not duplicate of that mentioned prior, but its duplicate of the question you mentioned. Thanks I found my answer.